# How does the Eclipse debugger gets the information about private variables inside the class?

Tags: java, eclipse

this was an interview question posed to me..I vaguely answered it uses Java reflections..but I was not sure. how does that work?

Comment: ... and how does it pause execution when in debug-mode for instance? I don't know the answer, (thus I post as comment), but I would guess it has it's own VM? It'll be interesting to see the answers.

Comment: @aioobe the same answer as the main question: it uses the java debugger which is part of the java framework :)

Comment: yeah :) I figured that out :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key to your question is almost certainly [`java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html), which allows the debugger to turn off the access control checks and poke around. Spring uses the same mechanism to get access to the variables for dependency injection.

Answer (score 7):

It uses the [Java Debugger](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html) which provides commands to do just that:

```
jdb print myObj.myInstanceField
```

Back in the old days there were really people doing this on a command line! :)

> NOTE: To display local variables, the containing class must have been compiled with the   javac -g option.